# How can I show full screen dialog or navigate to other screen when I click a Layout function?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

1. I have AppBarNavGraph and RootNavGraph.
2. I'd like to know two methods, Full Screen Dialog and also Navigating to a new Screen.

What I am trying to is..

```
Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(97.dp)
            .clickable {
                Dialog(onDismissResult = { /*TODO*/ }) {

                }
            }
        ,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
```

But in clickable, composable function is not callable.

So, What I tried is using this,

```
    val isClicked = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(97.dp)
            .clickable {
                isClicked.value = !isClicked.value
            },
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) 

    if(isClicked.value){
        // show full screen dialog or navigate to some screen.
    }
```

Here are two problems.

1. I tried with Dialog function.

```
Dialog(
    onDismissResult: () -> Unit,
    properties: DialogProperties = DialogProperties(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
)
```

but, this doesn't show full screen but just next item. (it's in GridLayout and when I click an item, the dialog needs to shows up to add the item.)

2. For navigation, I tried, varies ways, but I haven't found any clear solutions...

Could you please help me out? or any advices?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for a simple full screen popup

```kotlin
 var showPopup by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Box(Modifier
        .background(Color.Blue)
        .fillMaxSize()) {
        Button(onClick = { showPopup = true }) {
            Text("Show popup")
        }
    }

    if (showPopup) {
        Popup(
            onDismissRequest = { showPopup = false }
        ) {
            Box(Modifier
                .background(Color.Red)
                .fillMaxSize()) {
                Button(onClick = { showPopup = false },
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)) {
                    Text("Hide popup")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Though if you want proper navigation you should probably use [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation)